# order by clause with concatenated string in oracle 11

Tags: function, view, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I am getting below error while using order by clause on concatenated column.

"inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB"

Function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION LIST_PNUM (CID  in NUMBER) RETURN CLOB  
IS 
    l_text clob := NULL;
BEGIN 
  FOR cur_rec IN (SELECT C.E_DEVICE FROM CUSTOMER_PCN A, CP_DEVICE B, ET_DEVICE C WHERE A.C_ID = CID AND A.CP_ID = B.CP_ID AND B.ET_DEVICE_ID=C.ET_DEVICE_ID AND ROWNUM <= 250 ORDER BY C.E_DEVICE ) 
  LOOP     
     l_text := l_text || ',' || cur_rec.e_device;  
  END LOOP;  
  RETURN LTRIM(l_text, ',');  
END LIST_PNUM;
```

View:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "MYView" ("P_ID", "E_DEVICE") AS 
select p.p_id, LIST_PNUM(c.customer_id) AS e_device       
from Table .....  where Condition;
```

Select Statement:

```
select p_id, e_device from MYView order by e_device desc;
```

Error:

> "inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB"

Comment: You can't use a `CLOB` in an order by.

Comment: My concatenated string size is more than 4000, so I need clob

Comment: Then you can't use `order by`.